# Jquery POST, submitting a form while posting the data

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit, send

I used a tutorial to build my send button. I have two forms and depending on which one is selected, a different form needs to be submitted on "send" however this script does nothing but mess up my mailer. Can someone help me figure this out and explain to me what is going on? The form looks exactly how you think it would however i took out the form's method and action attributes because i figured they would be handled in the below script.

```
  "Send": (function() { 

            if(submitbutton == 1){
                var dataString = 'name:'+ name + '</br>email:' + email + '</br>phone:' + phone;  
                //alert (dataString);return false;  
                $.ajax({  
                     var name = $("input#name").val();  
                     var phone = $("input#phone").val();  
                     var email = $("input#email").val();  
                  type: "POST",  
                  url: "mailer.php",  
                  data: dataString,  
                  success: function() {  
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                  }  
                });  
                return false;  

            }

            else if(submitbutton == 2){
                var dataString = 'name:'+ name + '</br>email:' + email + '</br>phone:' + phone;  
                //alert (dataString);return false;  
                $.ajax({  
                     var name = $("input#name2").val();  
                     var phone = $("input#phone2").val();  
                     var email = $("input#email2").val();  
                  type: "POST",  
                  url: "mailer2.php",  
                  data: dataString,  
                  success: function() {  
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                  }  
                });
                return false;  
            }
            else if(submitbutton == 0){ 
                $("#error").css("display", "");
            }

        }),
```

Comment: what does `mess up my mailer` mean? need to be more specific about what your problem is. Also where is `submitbutton` defined?

Comment: It is defined earlier in the script, i didnt want to overwhelm anyone with all of my code. And on "send", an email is sent with the html in from my mailer.php but all of the values are blank meaning the values arnt posting properly. also, the dialog box wont close after send leading me to believe there is a problem with my ajax syntax

Comment: dialog close is due to context of `this` is lost inside `$.ajax`. Defnine the `this` elemnt as variable outside of ajax As for data, inspect request made in console network tab to see what is sent, and also check for erorrs thrown

Comment: The dialog close works perfectly now, thank you! but i dont understand what youre saying about the data. Im kind of new to this.

also, isnt there a way for me to define my datastring as all of the inputs within the form? and why do i have to set my datastring up with html+jquery, if that info in the datastring is being sent to my mailer.php why is the html necessary? wouldnt it mess things up? and do i need to do anything special with my mailer.php other than what i would do if i had a simple html form with a submit button and an action/method?

Comment: you have 2 scripts at play...browser javascript and server php. Need to narrow down where problem lies. In a browser console can inspect the request itself and see all the data sent/received, status, headers etc. Hit F12..Chrome built in dev tools and Firebug for Firefox are most common debugging consoles

Comment: It just says mailer.php post. would it help if you saw the site? the url is laserawayfat.com

Comment: but there is a lot more detail available there... need to click on it and probe around until you can see the data sent....is status 200?

Comment: status is 200, also it says the form data= name:undefined</br>phone:undefined</br>email:undefined
which seems fishy, does that mean it isnt getting the posted values from the html form?

Comment: yes it does....I see the problem now....you define `dataString` before you define the variables it contains like `email`. Right under `dataString =` write  `console.log(dataString)` run code while console is open, will see it output there

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: datastring is not defined. also, once i put that in the form stopped closing and it stopped sending, did you mean for that to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One notable problem in the javascript is you are defining `dataString` prior to defining the variables it contains like `email`.

ALso the `dataString` is not valid form encoding. It should look like `'email=foo@foo.com&name=foo'` once it is compiled. It can't have html in it

It is simpler passing an object to `data` of `$.ajax` and let jQuery compile it for you or use `$('#formId').serialize()` to gather all the data in a whole form

Try this instead:

```
var data = {
    name: $("input#name").val(),
    email: $("input#email").val(),
    phone: $("input#phone").val()
}
var $dialog=$(this)
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mailer.php",
    data: data,
    success: function () {
        $dialog.dialog("close");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for your time and knowledge. I own you one!